# Listview does not populate songs from sd card in fragments

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

> I m in process to make an app which will fetch the songs from the sd card and 
>   populate in listview. but for some reason it does not populate and display 
>   blank fragment. Can you please help what might be the reason causing this 
>   problem. Thank you.

**bellasongs.java**

```
public class BellaSongs extends ListFragment {

    private ArrayList<ModelBellaSongs> BellaSongList;
    private ListView Bellasongviews;
    Context context;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bella_songs, container, false);
        Bellasongviews = (ListView)rootview.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        BellaSongList = new ArrayList<ModelBellaSongs>();
        return rootview;
    }

    public void getBellaSongList() {
        ContentResolver musicResolver = context.getContentResolver();
        Uri musicUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, null, null, null, null);

        if (musicCursor != null && musicCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int titlecolumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
            int idcolumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
            int artistcolumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);

            do {
                long thisId = musicCursor.getLong(idcolumn);
                String thistitle = musicCursor.getString(titlecolumn);
                String thisartist = musicCursor.getString(artistcolumn);
                BellaSongList.add(new ModelBellaSongs(thisId, thistitle, thisartist));
            } while (musicCursor.moveToNext());
        }
        getBellaSongList();

        Collections.sort(BellaSongList, new Comparator<ModelBellaSongs>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(ModelBellaSongs a, ModelBellaSongs b) {
                return a.getTitle().compareTo(b.getTitle());
            }
        });

        BellaSongsAdapter bellasongsadapter = new BellaSongsAdapter(getActivity(),BellaSongList);
            Bellasongviews.setAdapter(bellasongsadapter);
    }
}
```

**adapter.java**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">


<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

**bellasongsadapter.java**

```
public class BellaSongsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<ModelBellaSongs> bellasongs;
    private LayoutInflater songdetails;

    public BellaSongsAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<ModelBellaSongs>thesongs){
        bellasongs = thesongs;
        songdetails = LayoutInflater.from(c);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return bellasongs.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LinearLayout songLayout=(LinearLayout)songdetails.inflate(R.layout.singlelist_item,parent,false);
        TextView titleview=(TextView)songLayout.findViewById(R.id.text_song_name);
        TextView artistview=(TextView)songLayout.findViewById(R.id.text_artist_name);

        ModelBellaSongs currentsongs = bellasongs.get(position);
        titleview.setText(currentsongs.getTitle());
        artistview.setText(currentsongs.getArtist());
        songLayout.setTag(position);

        return songLayout;
    }
}
```

Comment: Returned cursor is not empty? Please attach BellaSongsAdapter.class

Comment: @YuriiTsap here I added the adapter class. is it correct.

Answer (score 1):

I think your id refrence is not correct

```
Bellasongviews = (ListView)rootview.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

Make sure your this `android.R.id.list` id is correct it should start from `R.id.yourId`

Dont import `android.R` here import your project `R` here.

Check id your XML Layout file or paste it too here in your question.

Comment: Earlier I used the R.id.customid but in runtime it throws an exception that id should include android following R.id.customid.

Comment: I have added the xml. i have changed the id from `android.R.id.list` to `R.id.list` in songs.java but eventually changed in xml from `android:id/list` to `@+id/list` but still it does not populate the listview in runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Looking through your code I see the method getBellaSingList().This mmethod is retrieving data, and even calling itself recurrently, but it is not called inside the `onCreateView()`. So technically - you are not populating your dataset. You need to call it while initializing your views - and please verify logic of this method.

Comment: thank you for your valuable response. i will consider. i m kind of not sure which method should i use here between `onActivityCreated` and `onViewCreated`. what should i consider according to you.

Comment: I prefer to do it onActivityCreated()